# Поиск границ в интервалах python

Tags: python, python-3.x, выборка

Программа должна запрашивать и выводить левую границу первого интервала и правую границу последнего интервала.
Не понимаю почему вылазит ошибка о неправильном синтаксисе.
Подскажите

[sample.csv](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/2zuV/52JeyPQHk)
Ошибка

```
  File "<ipython-input-6-7b807aac05ba>", line 34
    if current_interval=my_interval:
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Пример кода

```
import csv
import math

Sample=[]
with open("sample.csv", encoding="ANSI") as V:
    SR=csv.reader(V, delimiter = ";")
    for row in SR:
        Sample.append(float(row[0]))
print(Sample)

aggregate=Sample

# Объём выборки
N=len(aggregate)
print("Объём выборки (N): ", N)

# Рекомендуемое кол-во интервалов группировки
m=1+(math.log10(N)/math.log10(2))
print("Рекомендуемое кол-во интервалов (m): ", "%.0f" % m)

# Наибольшее и наименьшее значение выборки
min_volue=min(aggregate)
max_volue=max(aggregate)
print("Наименьшее значение выборки (min volue): ", min_volue)
print("Наибольшее значение выборки (max volue): ", max_volue)

# Ввод кол-во интервалов группировки
kol_interval=int(input("Введите кол-во интервалов (kol_interval): "))

# Величина интервала
delta=((max_volue-min_volue)/kol_interval)
print("Величина интервала (delta): ", "%.0f" % delta)

# Номер интервала
my_interval=int(input("Введите номер интервала: "))

if my_interval>kol_interval:
    print("Вы ввели номер несуществующего интервала")
else:
    current_interval=1
    # цикл по всем элементам выборки
    for x in aggregate:
        if current_interval=my_interval:
            print("Первое значение в выбранном интервале: ", x)
            s=0
            while s<delta-1:
                x=x+1
                s=s+1
                print("Последнее значение в вабранном интервале: " x)
        else:
            s=0
            while s<delta:
                x=x+1
                s=s+1
            current_interval=current_interval+1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a = b` это присвоение, `a` станет равной `b`

`a == b` это сравнение `a` и `b`

поэтому:

```
if current_interval=my_interval:
```

нужно поменять на:

```
if current_interval == my_interval:
```